# Log rotation based on monthly and log retention for 30 days in RollingFileAppender of log 4j

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j, rollingfileappender

Hi need to configure the RollingFileAppender to rotate the log based on daily basis and delete the old log files which are 30 days old, can some on help me with the log4j.prepoerties for this configuration. I want to switch from DailyRollingFileAppender to RollingFileAppender as the DailyRollingFileAppender doesnt have the flexibility for deletion

Answer (score 8):

Switching to `RollingFileAppender` is a pretty common thing to do. However, you can't configure it to keep log for 30 days. `RollingFileAppender` limits are set by size.
You can specify the size of each log file and the number of them you want to keep. For example:

```
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

That will keep up to 10 files of 50MB. While you can't control the timeframe the logs will cover, you can be sure log won't fill your disk.